# PodTopologyConstraints - DoNotSchedule not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I tried to use PodTopologySpreadConstraint to organize our deployment engine, and to spread replicas across zones.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 4 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      topologySpreadConstraints:
      - maxSkew: 1
        topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
        whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
        labelSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: nginx
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: platform
        operator: Equal
        value: "true"
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: nodes
                operator: In
                values:
                - platform
```

I expected that, if I have just one node labeled "platform", the scheduler needs to run just one replica of Nginx, and others need to be in a "pending" state because "DoNotSchedule" constraint is not satisfied.

But the deployment running the 4 replicas in the same node/zone, even that "DoNotSchedule" defined.

```
➜ kubectl get pods -o wide | grep nginx-deployment
nginx-deployment-6cbbb547c-6qvrg   1/1     Running            0               15m     192.168.33.28    ip-192-168-42-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal     <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6cbbb547c-cgbcf   1/1     Running            0               15m     192.168.37.251   ip-192-168-42-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal     <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6cbbb547c-dlqvd   1/1     Running            0               15m     192.168.47.173   ip-192-168-42-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal     <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6cbbb547c-hkgzc   1/1     Running            0               15m     192.168.39.27    ip-192-168-42-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal     <none>           <none>
```

and i just have one node labeled "platform"

```
➜ kubectl get nodes -l app=platform
NAME                                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-192-168-42-2.sa-east-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   4h45m   v1.22.15-eks-fb459a0
```

Does anyone have any idea what I made wrong?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to infrastructure and deployment, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Turing85 i love you <3